# Table Schema recommendation

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project where users can create their own items and their fields.Here is a simple demonstration. A user creates a category (Hardware) this creates a new table called Hardware with auto generated column (ID) - the query then update (Categories Table) with a new category (Hardware - only used to list previously created categories).

Last step in the query, the auto-generated id in the Hardware table is then inserted in items table along with category type and category Account.

I would like to be able to view all items created in each category table that is related to this account (which in-turn is a separate table)  -- How would you go about accomplishing this.

The task is for our company to create CRM system.. so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you would be better off adopting the [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Comment: @eggyal Thanks. i will give your suggestion a try.